# Anisotropic (linear) algebraic group: etymologic origin

Tags: terminology, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, motivation

A pretty naive question:
An  [*anisotropic*](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Anisotropic_group) algebraic (linear) group over a field $k$ is a
linear algebraic group
$G$ defined over $k$ and of $k$-rank zero,
i.e. not containing non-trivial $k$-split tori
(Ref.: A. Borel, Linear algebraic groups,  [Zbl 0186.33201](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0186.33201)).

Question: What is the intuition behind this terminology in context
of algebraic groups? Etymologically *isotropic* is Greek
for "the same in every direction."

In other fields of mathematics the same name is used also for  [isotropic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Fixed_points_and_stabilizer_subgroups) (=stabilizers)
and  [isotropic quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_quadratic_form).

The geometric intuition for the name isotropic group is
motivated plausibly [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740190/why-are-isotropy-groups-named-as-such) by Matt. About the usage of word 'isotropic' for
isotropic quadratic forms I'm not sure.

Is there any geometric motivation for the terminology *'anisotropic'* used for algebraic linear group defined above? Somehow it's geometry should reflect the property that
'something' there NOT behaves "the same in all directions."

Does it have any geometrical motivation or is it just a
'name'? My ingenuous attempt to explain the name is to interpret the split torus $T_k \cong \mathbb{G}_m^n$ as the *sphere* analoga for algebraic groups and the sphere is something where 'all directions are geometrically coequal', i.e. there is no distinguished direction, so maybe the name isotropic.

And an anisotropic algebraic group by definition above not contains such guy. Is this exactly the original heuristic motivation for the name *anisotropic* in context of algebraic groups by it's founder? Jaques Tits?

Comment: I can't say anything definitive about the actual history but if I had to guess, I would guess the name comes from the special case of quadratic forms; I believe the algebraic group $SO(V, q)$ attached to a quadratic form $q$ is anisotropic iff the quadratic form $q$ is, or something like that. I don't understand the quadratic form case, though.

Comment: I would agree with Qiaochu's guess. I would think that Paul Garrett will know for sure.

Comment: @AlexYoucis, ah, :) in fact I would _not_ claim to know with any certainty... but since the early 1970s it has made sense to me that (reductive...) algebraic groups without any split torus would be called "anisotropic", because that use was completely consistent with the sense of the word for quadratic forms: as Qiaochu Yuan recalls, an orthogonal group is anistropic in the algebraic group sense if and only if it is anisotropic in the quadratic forms sense ($q(v)=0$ implies $v=0$). I did hear Jacques Tits talk about alg groups in Corvallis in '77, and this is consistent with what I recall.

Comment: ... oh, and, indeed, among classical groups, the only alg-gp-anistropic ones are the orthogonal, unitary, and skew-quaternion groups attached to the respective anisotropic "forms" (ok, and $SL(1,D)$ for division algebras). These are also the cases where there's an "inertia theorem", proving that "signature" is the only invariant, etc.