# Borel group acts on Lie-algebra $\mathfrak{p}$ of parabolic group $P$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compex Lie group with semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$,
the connected subgroup
$B$ of $G$ with Lie algebra
$\mathfrak{b} := \mathfrak{b} \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in R^{+}} \mathfrak{g}_{\alpha} $,
( here $R^{+}$ is the set of positive roots with respect the adjoint action of $\mathfrak{g} $ on itself) is called a *Borel subgroup*.

Moreover we say that a closed, complex analytic, and connected
subgroup $P$ of $G$ is parabolic if the quotient $G/P$ can be realized as
the orbit of the action of $G$ on projective space $\mathbb{P}( V)$ for
some representation $V$ of $G$. In
particular, $G/P$ is a projective algebraic variety.
(one can show that that any Borel subgroup $B$ of $G$ is parabolic.)

In Fulton-Harris' [Representation Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0979-9) on page 384
is stated that if we assume that a parabolic group $P$ contains
a Borel subgroup $B$, (indeed, that's always doable after suitable conjugation
by Claim 23.47), then the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{p}$ of $P$ is a
subspace of $\mathfrak{g}$ containing $\mathfrak{b}$ and
invariant under the action of $ B$ on $\mathfrak{g}$; recall
$G$ (and therefore $B$ acts on $\mathfrak{g}$ by the adjoint representation.

Question about the last claim seems obscure to me. Why the Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{b}$ of $P$ is *invariant* under the action by $B$? The adjoint action of
$B$ preserves clearly by construction it's own Lie algebra $\mathfrak{b}$; compare also to the
Claim 23.45 on page 383. But I not see why $B$ preserves also
$\mathfrak{p}$, which by our assumption contains  $\mathfrak{b}$.

Comment: Well, $B$ is a subgroup of $P$, which stabilizes _its_ own Lie algebra! :)

Comment: ah yes, of course I see. Sorry for dump question

Comment: @paulgarrett: By the way, it's a funny coincidence, Mr Garrett. A few days ago I asked the following question about the etymologic origin for the name anisotropic algebraic groups

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4548361/anisotropic-linear-algebraic-group-etymologic-origin


and in a comment Alex Youcis remarked that possibly you could know something more about it. Could you borrow some time to say something about that?

Comment: I did comment there... I can't claim to know for sure the history of that usage... but, as I commented there, after seeing Siegel's and others' use with orthogonal groups, the "extension" to algebraic groups did not surprise me c. 1970. And my recollections of Borel and Tits talking about alg groups (e.g., classification) is consistent with that "natural" re-use of the word, consistent with the quadratic form (and orthogonal group) case. :)

Comment: I think the point about the main statement is that $\mathfrak p$ is invariant under the action of $B$, which is non-trivial.